# Not able to install library on Azure databricks cluster

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

So, while validating the pipeline created in azure data factory.
I am facing this issue while running azure databricks linked service.

Error details:
**Run result unavailable: job failed with error message Library installation failed for library due to user error for jar: "dbfs:/mnt/mopireport/TeamsAnalyticsCore-v9.jar" . Error messages: Library installation attempted on the driver node of cluster 0805-090147-ulpmkivi and failed. Please refer to the following error message to fix the library or contact Databricks support. Error Code: DRIVER_LIBRARY_INSTALLATION_FAILURE. Error Message: java.lang.Throwable: shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this resource type.**

Background:
This library is mounted to dbfs url (verified the mount is success)
Databricks is pointing to right cluster (verified)
I have permissions to edit and publish data pipeline in ADF.

Alternate tried:

1. I tried using adfss instead of wasbs for mounting, but wasbs is the right one. As it does and adfss gives error.
2. Directly goto cluster -> libraries -> install new -> select "DBFS/ADLS" as library source and type as JAR and try upload. this upload also fails with same message as above.

Comment: I am able to install a library via uploading the JAR. But that doesn't points to same path and so can not be used to reference while running pipeline.

Comment: can you do `dbutils.fs.ls("/mnt/mopireport")` ? How the data factory is authenticated to databricks? What kind of the mount point is it - not the passthrough mount point?

Comment: I used access token and mount is done via using SAS.  I think may be service principal way of access will work from databricks to trying to use that now.